# How can I clean my numeric entries given a pattern, R?

Tags: r, gsub

I uploaded some data from a Wikipedia article. The url is: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_number_of_police_officers

I used the XML package and it worked just fine. However when I read the data the numbers have an unnecesary pattern.

Here's the code I used to read and upload the data:

```
library(XML)
u <- 'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_number_of_police_officers'
t <- readHTMLTable(u)
t1 <- t[1]
write.csv(t1, 'test1.csv', row.names = F)
d <- read.csv('test1.csv',colClasses = 'character')
```

I need to eliminate both the 700xxxx000000000 and the numbers in brackets at the end, in order to remain with the digits after the zeros.

For example the number in the first row is 
    7005122000000000000122,000[3]
and I need:
    122,000

Any suggestions? I thought about using gsub or any similar function, however I would'n know which pattern to look. I could do it by hand but it is not as efective.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use `sub`, too. For example like this:

```
d[, c(2, 4)] <- sapply(d[, c(2, 4)], 
                       sub, 
                       pattern = ".*0{8,}([0-9,]+).*", 
                       replacement = "\\1")
head(d)
#          NULL.Country NULL.Size NULL.Year NULL.Police.per.100.000.people
# 1         Afghanistan   122,000      2012                            401
# 2      American Samoa       200      2012                            720
# 3             Andorra       237      2012                            278
# 4 Antigua and Barbuda       600      2012                            733
# 5           Argentina   205,902      2000                            558
# 6           Australia    49,242      2009                            217
```

Comment: You are welcome. However, @jdharrison's `elFun` solution should be the preferable `{XML}` way to go instead of post processing the data. I didn't know it was possible to alter `readHTMLTable` - learned sth :).

Answer (score 2):

Define a modified elFun:

```
testFun <- function(x){xmlValue(xmlChildren(x)$text)}
out <- readHTMLTable(u, elFun = testFun)[[1]]

> head(out)
  Country    Size Year Police per\n100,000 people
1         122,000 2012                        401
2             200 2012                        720
3             237 2012                        278
4             600 2012                        733
5         205,902 2000                        558
6          49,242 2009                        217
```

Explanation:

Some of the entries have multiple elements in a node like:

```
> xmlChildren(getNodeSet(htmlParse(u), "//table[1]/tr/td")[[534]])
$span
<span style="display:none" class="sortkey">7004500000000000000</span> 

$text
50,000 

$sup
<sup id="cite_ref-100" class="reference">
  <a href="#cite_note-100"><span>[</span>100<span>]</span></a>
</sup>
```

We target the elements that are "TEXT" nodes:

```
> xmlValue(xmlChildren(getNodeSet(htmlParse(u), "//table[1]/tr/td")[[534]])$text)
[1] "50,000"
```

rather then `span` or `sup` in the above example.